# What is the bound on the error that is given by Taylor's inequality?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have this problem here that I'm not sure how to solve. Consider the polynomial $1 - \large\frac {x^2}{2!}$  as an approximation to $\cos(x)$ on the closed interval $-1 \le x \le 1$. What is the best bound on the error that is given by Taylor's inequality?

I tried finding the $3^{rd}$ derivative of the function, which gives $\sin(x)$. Maximum value of this is $\sin(x)$, taking $x = 1$. Largest absolute value of $x^{n+1}$ is $x^4$, which equals to $1$. So I thought the answer, according to the error formula, would be $\large\frac{\sin(1)}{6}$. But apparently the correct answer is $\frac {1}{24}$.

Can someone please explain why this is so? Would really appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: There are several different forms for the error in Taylor's theorem (Lagrange form, Cauchy's form, integral form). All are correct. Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm using Taylor's Inequality, I'm not sure which form is that?

Comment: I think you can use the fact that the polynomial given is the 3rd order Taylor polynomial for $\cos x$ at $a=0$, so you can use $|R_{3}(x)|$ to estimate the error.

Comment: Wait isn't it a 2nd order Taylor polynomial? Since it's $x^2$?

Comment: Okay I realise that sin(x) < 1 so now I keep getting the answer of $\frac 16$. Is this correct, i.e. answer given is wrong, or am I wrong?